# Java: Reading PDF bookmark names with itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I am working with a single PDF containing multiple documents.  Each document has a bookmark.  I need to read the bookmark names for a reconciliation application that I am building.  The code below is not working for me.  I am trying to place the bookmark name in the *title* string.  Can anyone provide any guidance?  Thank you very much.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\Work\\Input.pdf");
List<HashMap<String,Object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);

for(int i = 0; i < bookmarks.size(); i++){

    HashMap<String, Object> bm = bookmarks.get(i);
    String title = ((String)bm.get("Title"));

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not working? i tried your code and all the top level title are returned.

Comment: I thought that it was "not working" because the title variable was not listed under Variables. I did some further testing to validate that the title variable is being populated with the bookmark titles.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You are not taking into account that bookmarks are stored in a tree structure with branches and leaves (in the PDF specification, it's called the *outline tree*).

As @Todoy says in the comment section, your code works for the top-level, but if you want to see *all* the titles, you need to use a recursive method that also looks at the `"Kids"`.

Take a look at [this code sample](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/interactive/FetchBookmarkTitles):

```
public void inspectPdf(String filename) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> bookmarks = SimpleBookmark.getBookmark(reader);
    for (int i = 0; i < bookmarks.size(); i++){
        showTitle(bookmarks.get(i));
    }
    reader.close();
}

public void showTitle(HashMap<String, Object> bm) {
    System.out.println((String)bm.get("Title"));
    List<HashMap<String,Object>> kids = (List<HashMap<String,Object>>)bm.get("Kids");
    if (kids != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < kids.size(); i++) {
            showTitle(kids.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

The `showTitle()` method is recursive. It calls itself if an examined bookmark entry has kids. With this code snippet, you can walk through all the branches and leaves of the outline tree.